# Does an admissions committee check if a student retook a class

Tags: graduate-admissions, coursework

Many schools around me (in asia) allow a student to retake any class, regardless of grade, and replace it on their transcript.  Is it normal for an admissions committee to query if the school an applicant is from allows this, or is it not thought of at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the class shows up twice on your transcript, the committee will know you retook it.  But they probably won't care.

If it doesn't, it won't even occur to them to ask.  (At least in my experience.)

Comment: So if a student had one year inbetween applying to grad school and finishing undergrad, you would advise that it is a good idea to retake any classes to improve their GPA, as no one would think they have 'inflated' their gpa.  Given they would not be doing other more interesting work?

Comment: Just for context, this question came about because of a recent question I saw where they asked, should i retake a class for gpa or do research.